# Perturbated sum of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory

It is $(X_{jm}), m\in\mathbb{N}, j\le m$ i.i.d with $E X_{11} = 0$ and $EX_{11}^2=1$ (no higher moments). Let $(v_{jm})_{j\le m}, (e_{lm})_{l\le m} \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be orthonormal bases and $a_{jm} \in (1\pm \varepsilon)$. Does it hold that

$$\frac{1}{m} \sum_{j=1}^m a_{jm} \left( \left( \sum_{l=1}^m X_{lm} (v_{jm},e_{lm})\right)^2-1\right) \to 0$$

in probability (or in $L^1$)? The statement is obviously true, if either $v_{lm}=e_{lm}$, or $a_{lm}=1$, and I am curious, wether also the general case is true...

Comment: What does the notation $(1 \pm \varepsilon)$ mean?  Is that the interval $(1-\varepsilon, 1 + \varepsilon)$ or the set $\{1-\varepsilon, 1+\varepsilon\}$ or something different?

Answer (score 0):

In the case someone is interested in the answer. The statement is true. One can first consider the special case with finite fourth moments ($E [X_11^4]<\infty$), then the general statement follows with truncation. A proof of a similar statement can be found in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.04519.pdf (Proposition 4.8 for the special case, the general case on pages 30-32).